# Replace the current route with other route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In Angular 2.0 to navigate to other route we can use `route.navigate( [ 'routeName' ] )`. But this action will store the current route in browser history.
What is the method to replace the current route in browser history and navigate to new route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
navigateByUrl(url: string, _skipLocationChange?: boolean) : Promise<any>
```

or

```
navigateByInstruction(instruction: Instruction, _skipLocationChange?: boolean) : Promise<any>
```

on the `Router` and pass `true` to `_skipLocationChange` to achieve that effect.

(not tried myself yet though and the docs are vague but I think this is what you're looking for)

**Hint:** not yet supported in the new RC.1 router

Comment: Is this supported in router final release 3.0.0 now?

Comment: AFAIR this is supported now. I'm only on my phone therefore difficult to look it up.

Comment: It is. I just mixed up two version, so was having error. my bad.

Comment: The answer below using the same `.navigate()` method (so no need to change parameter logic) but achieves OP's goal via the `replaceUrl` option is more fitting.

Answer (score 7):

See this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html

You have to use the option replaceUrl instead of skipLocationChange. It will send you to the new url but the current one will NOT be preserved, so pressing back will not send you back to this page.

```
this.router.navigate(['login'],{replaceUrl:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it works on Angular RC.1 + versions

```
this.router.navigate(['login'],{skipLocationChange:true});
```

This will navigate to login route and not store login route in Browser History.